# TypeScript not immediately transpile in WebStorm

Tags: compilation, typescript, webstorm

I've been using WebStorm to create TypeScript for awhile now, and today it just suddenly stops transpiling TS to JS files. I do have correct FileWatcher and everything. Anyone got any idea? Wonder if WebStorm have a way to force transpiling all the TS files.

Thanks

Comment: After restart WebStorm, I got this message: Webstorm native file watcher executate not found". I've check the tsc folder and it's still there (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc). Not sure what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run this with node. Make sure the command is "node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc"

Comment: Is there anyway to run this without Node?

Comment: yes - at least on Mac. When installing typescript using npm, tsc executable is created in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin that runs tsc.js with node. If you select the tsc.js file as a Program in File Watcher settings, this indeed won't work. But selecting tsc executable directly works

Comment: Do we need to install Node for each project? Or just install once and it will work on every project on different folder?

Comment: `node` only once. Also you can install tsc globally e.g. `npm install -g typescript`

Answer (score 0):

Please open the /usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc with text editor - is it ok? Does it have executavble permissions? can you run it in terminal, like `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc <path to your ts>/your_file.ts>`?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem where WebStorm suddenly stopped creating .js files. Removing the file watcher and then letting WS create it again from scratch fixed the problem for me. This applies to WebStorm 8.

Comment: There are no watchers for Typescript anymore. It's handled by the "service".